# Dictionary.ContainsKey() vs. large arrays used for lookup, any alternative?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, lookup, hashset

I have a span of over 64 millions of ints (these are RGBA32 colors read as int32 from a 8192^2 PNG file, all positive and 2^31 - 1 excluded). I need to enumerate the different ints with a dictionary and have a bijection ints <-> [0, count[.

```
Span<int> intSpan = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("PNGFile").GetRawTextureData<int>();

Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new();

    for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < intSpan.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(intSpan[i]))
        {
            dictionary.Add(intSpan[i], count);

            count++;
        }
    }
```

511 ms to retrieve the 3412 different ints from the 8192^2 length span.

Now, let use a 2^31 - 1 length bool array instead.

```
bool[] bools = new bool[int.MaxValue];

for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < intSpan.Length; i++)
{
    if (!bools[intSpan[i]])
    {
        bools[intSpan[i]] = true;

        dictionary.Add(intSpan[i], count);

        count++;
    }
}
```

235 ms. Less than half. But that array takes over 2 GB of memory.

Using a 2^31 - 1 length Bitarray instead.

```
BitArray bitarray = new(int.MaxValue);
```

256 ms. Barely slower but 8 times less memory.

Using a regular 2^26 int array with bit shitfing.

```
int[] intArray = new int[(int)Mathf.Pow(2, 26)];

for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < intSpan.Length; i++)
{
    if (((intArray[intSpan[i] / 32] >> (intSpan[i] % 32)) & 1) == 0)
    {
        intArray[intSpan[i] / 32] |= (1 << (intSpan[i] % 32));

        dictionary.Add(intSpan[i], count);

        count++;
    }
}
```

160 ms.

Please challenge my apparent misconceptions and tell me what are better ways, in any sense, to do what these pieces of code do. Problems of enumeration of the different elements of very large collections has taken a significant part of my time for years.

The poor performance of Dictionary.ContainsKey() or Hashset.Contains() is even more apparent (and become an obstacle) with less primitive structs such as Vector3, or pairs of vectors (tuples), etc. where straight replacement by lookup arrays is not possible for size reasons.

Comment: What misconceptions?  I don't find your results particularly surprising.  If raw CPU performance is your #1 priority, then perhaps C# is not the right language for you.  You could do this analysis in C++ pretty easily.

Comment: I don't think C# would be any slower than C++ here, once the garbage collector has finished running. That's still machine code, in the end.

Comment: _"The poor performance of Dictionary.ContainsKey() or Hashset.Contains() is even more apparent"_ - your code does not measure performance of `ContainsKey`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Add` on a dictionary is _still_ a lookup. Doing `ContainsKey` + `Add` is two searches in the dictionary. You could just call `TryAdd` directly and that'd be probably faster.

Comment: Also I highly recommend for cases when building relatively large dictionaries - specify the capacity (if you can estimate the length).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, with only 3412 calls to `Add` the performance gain of using `TryAdd` is negligible here. Performance is used by the 8192 * 8192 calls to `ContainsKey`.

Comment: Also basically that is the culprit - dictionary  (as arguably any hashtable in the nutshell) will need to sacrifice some speed to preserve memory. In C# dictionaries use bucketing approach to handle collision and the size of index space is limited to the initial capacity (it uses prime numbers AFAIK and after adding first element it will have capacity of 3 I believe), which can lead to quite a lot of hash collisions due to hash function being something like `i % capacity`. So on some early iterations you can have a lot of collisions which will result in almost `O(n)` searches.

Comment: @GuruStron What would it measure other than that?

Comment: I'm also not clear what misconceptions you have. A Dictionary is a high-level construct designed to bucketize arbitrary data types using some hash code in a space-efficient manner, while still providing fast lookup. Yes of course you can optimize the case when you are only dealing with integers, and indeed a bit-shifted array probably is the fastest, if more complex. How would your array work if you were dealing with some random object? Structs have a separate copying problem, you may need to box them inside another class to make them efficient.

Comment: During expansions the number of buckets will be expanded also so in the later iterations you should have better performance for `ContainsKey` but again - this is subject of the data, if you have 3412 integers in theory they can be placed into a very small number of buckets if your are very unlucky with your data, leading to "bad" search times.

Comment: Also you should pre-size your dictionary `Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new(intSpan.Length);`. Anyway, what exactly is your question: How to optimize lookup of a huge collection of int32? Why is Dictionary so slow compared to your specific optimized example? Is your implementation of Dictionary efficient?

Comment: @Charlieface _"Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new(intSpan.Length);"_ - I have initially made the same suggestion (edited it out) but based on the _"to retrieve the 3412 different ints from the 8192^2 length span."_ - it can be a bit of an overkill from size standpoint.